# In Inception, how did everyone finally get out of dream Level 1?

Tags: inception

Once the job was complete, everyone was back at level 1. But how did they manage to get out of there and wake up, if they couldn't kill themselves without ending up in limbo and the armed subconscious were still around trying to kill them?

Comment: Per the dupe, my instinct is that they just sat tight until the timer ran out.